# Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined (using vue_cli , vuetify and electron)

Tags: vue.js, electron, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vue-cli

I have an Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined error in an electron application mixed with vue_cli and vuetify
I'm new to Webpack and don't know where to start looking. Can anyone help?

Webpack config

My expectation was to resolve the error and ensure that the application functions smoothly across different environments without encountering the 'process is not defined' issue."

``

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');
const pathModule = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

// Charger les variables d'environnement à partir du fichier .env

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ],
  // Options de configuration de Webpack
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      // Utiliser webpack.DefinePlugin pour injecter les variables d'environnement dans le code
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      //  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV) ,
        // Injecter les variables d'environnement à partir de  dotenv
        process: 'process'

      })
    ],
    resolve: {
      fallback: {
        'path': require.resolve('path-browserify'),
        'fs': false,
        'process/browser': false,
      }
    }
  },
 ` pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }`
  }
});
```

``

Comment: Where and how do you get this error? Please share more debugging details.

Comment: hello Arkellys , i get this error my  google  web page when i run my local ip adress via this command npm run serve

Comment: Google web page? It's an Electron app, you should look at the Electron window and never at the browser's.

Comment: Indeed, I use live rendering via the webpage to see the real-time changes made to my project to avoid encapsulating it multiple times.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: "In fact, I can't have a real-time view of what I'm developing, even though the app is ultimately intended to be installed on a computer. The error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined' prevents me from having the rendering of my app on a web page.

Comment: Because an Electron app should not be looked at from a web page, that's what I'm trying to tell you. You should only use the Electron window.

Comment: "Thank you very much. I was trying to complicate things with a problem that didn't even concern me. Indeed, I can also see the changes made to my project in real-time using the command 'npm run electron:serve'."